# Langchain | ImportError: cannot import name 'create_model' from 'langchain_core.runnables.utils'

Tags: python, langchain

I just installed the latest version of langchain in a new empty conda env (python 3.11.7) using pip. Pip now lists me the following langchain packages:

```
langchain                            0.1.13
langchain-community                  0.0.29
langchain-core                       0.1.33
langchain-text-splitters             0.0.1
```

I just followed the basic tutorial on [Langchain Search Tools](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/tools/search_tools). However the very first import is already throwing an error.

```
from langchain.agents import AgentType
```

Error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_model' from 'langchain_core.runnables.utils'
```

Entire traceback for reference:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 7
      5 import openai
      6 from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
----> 7 from langchain.agents import AgentType
      8 from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
      9 from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\__init__.py:34
     31 from pathlib import Path
     32 from typing import Any
---> 34 from langchain_community.agent_toolkits import (
     35     create_json_agent,
     36     create_openapi_agent,
     37     create_pbi_agent,
     38     create_pbi_chat_agent,
     39     create_spark_sql_agent,
     40     create_sql_agent,
     41 )
     42 from langchain_core._api.path import as_import_path
     44 from langchain.agents.agent import (
     45     Agent,
     46     AgentExecutor,
   (...)
     50     LLMSingleActionAgent,
     51 )

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\agent_toolkits\__init__.py:41, in __getattr__(name)
     39 def __getattr__(name: str) -> Any:
     40     if name in _module_lookup:
---> 41         module = importlib.import_module(_module_lookup[name])
     42         return getattr(module, name)
     43     raise AttributeError(f"module {__name__} has no attribute {name}")

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    124             break
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\agent_toolkits\powerbi\base.py:13
      7 from langchain_core.language_models import BaseLanguageModel
      9 from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.powerbi.prompt import (
     10     POWERBI_PREFIX,
     11     POWERBI_SUFFIX,
     12 )
---> 13 from langchain_community.agent_toolkits.powerbi.toolkit import PowerBIToolkit
     14 from langchain_community.utilities.powerbi import PowerBIDataset
     16 if TYPE_CHECKING:

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\agent_toolkits\powerbi\toolkit.py:9
      7 from langchain_core.language_models import BaseLanguageModel
      8 from langchain_core.language_models.chat_models import BaseChatModel
----> 9 from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate
     10 from langchain_core.prompts.chat import (
     11     ChatPromptTemplate,
     12     HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
     13     SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
     14 )
     15 from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import Field

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\__init__.py:27
      1 """**Prompt** is the input to the model.
      2 
      3 Prompt is often constructed
   (...)
     25 
     26 """  # noqa: E501
---> 27 from langchain_core.prompts.base import BasePromptTemplate, format_document
     28 from langchain_core.prompts.chat import (
     29     AIMessagePromptTemplate,
     30     BaseChatPromptTemplate,
   (...)
     35     SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
     36 )
     37 from langchain_core.prompts.few_shot import (
     38     FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate,
     39     FewShotPromptTemplate,
     40 )

File c:\Users\a704601\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\spie\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\prompts\base.py:31
     29 from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableConfig, RunnableSerializable
     30 from langchain_core.runnables.config import ensure_config
---> 31 from langchain_core.runnables.utils import create_model
     33 if TYPE_CHECKING:
     34     from langchain_core.documents import Document

ImportError: cannot import name 'create_model' from 'langchain_core.runnables.utils'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or an older langchain version where this works?